# SOS Game: Concept of Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: java

I am creating a game called SOS. It is a 3x3 board game and it has the same concept as Tic-Tac-Toe but in this game, the players cannot choose whether they will play as X or O, the only rule in this game is to form "SOS".

Our program should be terminated after all the positions are filled, and each formed "SOS" will be added to the player who formed "SOS".

My problem is about scoring. After entering SOS in the first row which is `(- - -)`, I tried to input "O" in the second row first column, and the player 2 will increment. It should not increment because it didn't satisfy the second else if in my program. Why is it happening?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SOS
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
{
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 String ar[] = {"-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"};
 int player1 = 0;
 int player2 = 0;
 int index = 0;

 for(int l = 0; l<3; l++)
 { 
   for(int j = 0; j<3; j++)
   {
     System.out.print(ar[j]);
   }
   System.out.print("\n");
 }

 for(int j = 0;j < 9;j++)
 {
  //Input position and letter
  System.out.println("Enter the position number: ");
  index = input.nextInt();
  input.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Enter (S or O): ");
  ar[index - 1] = input.nextLine();

  //Output for the game
  for(int l = 0; l<9; l++)
  {
    System.out.print(ar[l]);
    if(l == 2)
    {
      System.out.println();
    }
    else if(l == 5)
    {
      System.out.println();
    }
    else if(l == 8)
    {
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
  //condition
  if((ar[0]+ar[1]+ar[2]).equals("SOS")) 
  {
    if(j%2 == 0)
    {
      player1++;
      System.out.println("Player 1: "+player1+"    Player 2: "+player2);
    }
    else if( j % 2 != 0)
    {
      player2++;
      System.out.println("Player 1: "+player1+"    Player 2: "+player2);
    }
  }
  else if((ar[3]+ar[4]+ar[5]).equals("SOS"))
  {
    if(j%2 == 0)
    {
      player1++;
      System.out.println("Player 1: "+player1+"    Player 2: "+player2);
    }
    else if( j % 2 != 0)
    {
      player2++;
      System.out.println("Player 1: "+player1+"    Player 2: "+player2);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    System.out.println("Player 1: "+player1+"    Player 2: "+player2);
  }



  //end of condition

  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: in the first condition you have a two !
probably that is wrong... !!(ar[0][0].equalsIgnoreCase("")

Comment: Do you have a deeper explanation of the game you could link to (maybe an example round or two)? I'm not sure I understand the constraints here.

Comment: You have a double negation on your code : `!!(ar[0][0].equalsIgnoreCase(""))` ... Try fixing that

Answer (score 2):

The bug is occurring in this section of your code:

```
if((ar[0]+ar[1]+ar[2]).equals("SOS"))
```

After the first player correctly enters SOS into these positions, this statement will always be true. Which means that your nested if/else is running on every turn:

```
    if(j%2 == 0)
    {
      player1++;
    }
    else if( j % 2 != 0)
    {
      player2++;
    }
```

During the 4th turn, j will be equal to 3. (j%2 != 0) is true, which increments player2.

If you continue running the program, you will see player1 and player2 continually incrementing on every turn because the initial if will always be true.

Comment: Oh I see. So how can i fix that?